# We refer to X for standard notations and definitions from Y

Tags: soft-question, notation, terminology

I'm having problems with my mathematical English, so I'd like to ask for your help! Is it correct to write something like "Unless stated otherwise, we refer to [1] and [2], respectively, for standard notations and definitions from set theory and ring theory."? Are there some better ways to phrase the same concept? I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask for certain questions, but I tried in an English chat, and they recommended to ask mathematicians.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good English sentence to me (I'm not sure why someone in an English chat would recommend you post the question to mathematicians - (English) mathematical writing is still English prose).

Comment: They say that mathematicians prefer certain expressions to others, no matter if they are written in a correct English.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing a paper, then you could say something like:
"The nomenclature used in our paper for set theory and ring theory are borrowed from [1] and [2] respectively, unless stated otherwise."

Just my two cents

Comment: You mean nomenclature :)